# I'm trying to make a panel on the main screen of the app that will appear every time I start the application. Is it possible to do this in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, panel

I am developing a project in Unity and every time I enter the application I need to create a dynamic panel where the user's tasks for that day will be listed. In other words, when the user enters the platform, this panel will appear once on the main page, but when he comes to the main page again as long as does not leave the platform, the panel will not appear, if he closes the application and opens it again, this panel will appear again. I would be very grateful if you could help me with how to do this.

Comment: Based on your details, you need to have 3 scenes: 1.Loading, 2.Main, 3.Other. Create a DoNotDestroyOnLoad object on your loading scene that loads the data you wish to show and display it on the main scene. Since this object is created on the Loading Scene and this scene loads once, the data you want to show is disaplyed once

Comment: Another solution is to store a variable in your playerPrefs, its value is set to true on loading scene and set it to false in main scene after the player has closed the menu. check the value of this variable when main scene is loaded. I could post an example if you wish